# Using LOOKUP, need "result_range" blank if "search_key" not found

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to coordinate data between two separate sheets using the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(A3,Housed!A:A,Housed!B:B)
```

However, when that formula is applied to destination cells for which "`search_key`" is not found among "`search_range`", the output of "`result_range`" for the previous cell in the destination column is repeated, as described in Google Docs Editors Help:

> If search_key is not found, the item used in the lookup will be the value that’s immediately smaller in the range provided. For example, if the data set contains the numbers 1, 3, 5 and search_key is 2, then 1 will be used for the lookup.

This is a problem for me, because data is placed in cells where it doesn't apply, and I would like these cells, for which "`search_key`" is not found in "`search_range`" to remain blank.

I've tried incorporating `VLOOKUP` instead, but get a `#REF` error, it seems due to evaluating data on a separate sheet, or otherwise outside the stated range. And I can't seem to wrap my head around incorporating an `IF` formula into the array in a way that gives me the desired outcome.

The original spreadsheet contains confidential information, so I cannot share that link here; however, I've duplicated the necessary components [here:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eZS3q7_PaAOwwHMKmPEfLLzizFJn3FsuEyQytNKlggg/edit?usp=sharing)

Does anyone have ideas or fixes for this?

Is there something I need to add?

Am I using the wrong formula?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `vlookup`, not `lookup` (suggestion: never use `lookup`). The following function achieves your objective:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, False))
```

Explanation:

- Second parameter of vlookup is the range that includes both the column to search (must be the first one), and the column from which result is to be taken.
- Third parameter specifies that the result is taken from 2nd column
- `False` indicates that exact match is required
- `iferror` wrapper suppresses error messages, replacing them with blanks.

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP` with the last parameter (`IsSorted`) set FALSE can get very slow.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, other!A:A, 1) = A2, VLOOKUP(A2, other!A:B, 2), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `=IF(isna(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))=false,VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2),"")`